smartdiagram - control bubble node size properly
Following up on this question, I want all my bubbles to have the same diameter, without changing font family or size... is that possible?
This is my MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{A589D9}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{95C753}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{35BEC1}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{F16D64}
\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{F3C746}
\definecolor{mypink}{HTML}{F371AF}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{666666}

\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\tikzset{bubble node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.5
    }
}
\tikzset{bubble center node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.5
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \smartdiagramset{
        distance text center bubble=0.5cm,
        bubble center node size=3cm,
        bubble node size=3cm,
        distance center/other bubbles=1cm,
        bubble center node font=\huge\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\color{gray},
        bubble node font=\huge\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\color{gray},
        bubble center node color=mypink,
        set color list = {mypurple, mygreen, myblue, myred, myyellow}
    }%
    \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
        team\\player,
        fast\\learner,
        motivated,
        organized,
        problem\\solver,
        precise%
    }%
\end{document}

Which produces this:

Note that the nodes are of varying diameters (even when I specify bubble center node size and bubble node size to be 3cm for all); they seem to be adjusted to the text inside of them.
Is there a way to have all nodes (including the center one if possible) to have the same diameter (regardless of the text inside of them)? This should be accomplished without changing font body and size. Thanks!

Your text wants more space than the (minimum) size of the bubbles give ... so it adjusts.
Here I doubled both sizes:

\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mypurple}{HTML}{A589D9}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{95C753}
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{35BEC1}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{F16D64}
\definecolor{myyellow}{HTML}{F3C746}
\definecolor{mypink}{HTML}{F371AF}
\definecolor{grey}{HTML}{666666}

\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\tikzset{bubble node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.5
    }
}
\tikzset{bubble center node/.append style={
        draw=none, opacity=0.5
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \smartdiagramset{
        distance text center bubble=0.5cm,
        bubble center node size=6cm,    % <<<
        bubble node size=6cm,           % <<<
        distance center/other bubbles=1cm,
        bubble center node font=\huge\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\color{gray},
        bubble node font=\huge\pgfsetfillopacity{1}\color{gray},
        bubble center node color=mypink,
        set color list = {mypurple, mygreen, myblue, myred, myyellow}
    }%
    \smartdiagram[bubble diagram]{%
        team\\player,
        fast\\learner,
        motivated,
        organized,
        problem\\solver,
        precise%
    }%
\end{document}


ah... of course! many thanks
